# use angular 2 data from rest api

Tags: json, rest, typescript, angular

I'm begining in Angular 2 , in the first I try to get data from JSON file and show it on a table and that's done , now I want to get data from rest api so I create my Restful webservices from Entity classes , I generate the CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter ( I use netbeans  and glassfish) and I get the link with JSON output , I replace the link in the api url in angular 2 but it doesn't work 
this in my Angular 2 employes.service

```js
@Injectable()
export class EmployesService {
    private empsUrl = 'localhost:25176/WebApplication4/app/employes';  // URL to web api

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getEmployes (){
        return this.http.get(this.empUrl)
           .map(res=> res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }
```

this is my employes.component

```js
export class EmployesComponent implements OnInit{
    emps: Employe[];
    error: any;
    mode = 'Observable';
errorMessage :string;
    constructor(private empService: EmployesService,private _elRef :ElementRef) { }
    getEmployes() {
      
        this.empService.getEmployes()
            .subscribe(
                employes => this.emps = employes,
                error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getEmployes();
```

this is my console Errors

```js
zone.js:101 XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:25176/WebApplication4/app/employes. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

thank you for helping

Comment: Please add the code from your images directly to your question.

Comment: Also please show us your `app/app.component.html`, since that's where the exception happens.

Comment: @rinukkusu my app.component.html has  the router link for EmployesComponent  [routerLink]="['Employes']

Comment: So what's on `line 154` in your `app/app.component.html`?

Comment: <a [routerLink]="['Employes']">Get Employes </a>

Comment: How are your routes defined?

Comment: @RouteConfig([
  {
    path: '/employes',
    name: 'Employes',
    component: EmployesComponent
  }
])

Comment: Could you try setting the router link to `[routerLink]="['/Employes']"`, please.

Comment: I dont have problems with router , it work but I have the problems with api

Comment: I do some changes in my main.ts so I have another types of Exceptions I will edit my console errors now

Comment: Change the URL to http:// type url